# Git Bash showing files with non-ASCII characters as modified

Tags: git, msysgit, git-extensions

I've just setup a new machine with a clean install of Windows 7, Git Extensions (2.32) which also installs msysGit 1.7.10.

Once I clone our local repo like so...:
git clone "Y:\SomeRepo"

... Running a git status shows a series of files as being modified, even though I've just cloned the repo. All of the files include non-ASCII characters like Æ, Ø and Å. Interestingly, there are four others in the team, also running Win7 with the same Git Extensions and msysGit version, and we've never run into the issue.

core.autocrlf is false, just as quotepath is off. All of these files are .png's so I don't think line ending conversion is an issue.

Any tips on where to start debugging/fixing this issue?

Comment: do you mean that the paths include these characters?

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov The filenames themselves include these characters and as such, they show up in the path when I do a git status. Before I set "quotepath off" they would be shown as "\nnn" instead of the actual character, though quotepath didn't help anything besides showing the actual character in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have committed the files with non-ASCII names with a non-Unicode Git for Windows version and need to [follow these instructions](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-for-Windows-Unicode-Support#wiki-Migrating_old_Git_for_Windows_repositories). As to why some of your teammates do not see this, maybe they are using a different locale on their Windows machines.

Comment: The files were indeed checked in by a Git version previous to 1.7.10 and were thus stored using ASCII code pages. While I couldn't get the guide steps to work, what I did was to simply copy the offending files out of the git repo, commit them as deletions, upgrade git to 1.7.10 and then add the files back in and commit them. All the other clients then needed to be upgraded to 1.7.10 and do a pull, after which it worked.